# Is it possible to wait different method to be invoked in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, task, observer-pattern

I have to methods and first one needs second one to be called. Either it can wait or it can try in loop. What is the best way to do it?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> First()
{
// I need wait for Second() to be called and get result from it to continue here.
}
// It is not gonna be called from First(), it is a callback from Web.
public IHttpActionResult Second()
{
return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Make also `Second` async and await the call to it in `First`.

Comment: `async Task<IHttpActionResult> Second()` and `await Second()` in `First`

Comment: @Sandhagen, therefore can I continue to method only Second() to be called?
Nguyen, I will try that.

Comment: Who should call First and Second?

Comment: Why don´t you just call `Second()` from `First()`? You could either block until it returns or await it asynchronously.

Comment: Hans, Second() should be called so First() can continue. mm8 What is the best way to wait for it?

Comment: Do you mean that some other code should call both First and Second (and First should wait)? If that is the case, can't you call Second first and pass the results to First? Or split First (call First_1, Second, First_2)

Answer (score 0):

## New Answer:

```
public class App
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> _tcsSquare;

        public async Task<int> First()
        {
            // I need wait for Second() to be called and get result from it to continue here.
            var result = await _tcsSquare.Task;
            return result;
        }

        // It is not gonna be called from First(), it is a callback from Web.
        public async Task Second(int x)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            _tcsSquare.SetResult(x * x);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _tcsSquare = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            var result = Task.Run(() => First());
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Second(5));

            Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
        }
    }
```

This code will start two tasks. Independent of each other. The `TaskCompletionSource` is a going to provision a Task for synchronization between two tasks.
As soon as second() sets Result with `_tcsSquare.Result = ....` statement. The wait inside `First()` ends.

You don't have to loop or check again every few seconds. It can wait till _tcsSquare gets a results.

More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8

## First Answer:

In asynchronous programming, it is common for one asynchronous operation, on completion, to invoke a second operation and pass data to it.

the framework suggests using `ContinueWith` function.

You'll have to change your order a little bit. Because 2nd function finishes first you should call really call it the first function.
Here is what your code might look like:

```
public class App
{
    public async Task<int> Run(Func<int, int> callback)
    {
        // start second() as a Task. 
        var secondTask = Task.Run(() => callback(5));

        // second() has completed
        var result = await secondTask.ContinueWith(
                output =>
                {
                    //use output of second() here using output.Result 
                    return output.Result * output.Result; // 625
                });

        return result;
    }

    public int second(int x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var result = Run(second).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

}
```

More here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Actually, second method is callback method and invoked by completely different request.

Calling it with await seems like I am invoking method myself. I was trying to find solution that I listen that method.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but now `second()` is a callback function. It is passed as a parameter `Func<int, int>`. If not this. then I didn't get the question yet. :)

Comment: Both of them are IHttpActionResult, I want first() to check if Second() is invoked.

Comment: You need a `TaskCompletionSource`. Let me put something together.